# How to make the HTMLTestRunner.py pythonfilename > result.html line inside python file to automatically create the html file?

Tags: python

I have a Python file named pythontc.py which consists of the below code:

```
import unittest
import genson
import requests,json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from jsonschema import validate

class TC1(tu.Tc):
    def setUp(self):
        with open('schema.json', 'q') as t:
            self.schema = t.read()
            self.file = t

    def test1(self):
        result =requests.get('http://localhost:8000/some/123/somename?attribute=somename&someid=123&provider=somename&refresh=true', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('USERNAME', 'Pass'))
        data = result.text
        print data

    def tearDown(self):
        self.file.close()
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            tu.main()
```

Now this exexutes in cmd now i want to get that result in html format using htmltest runner.

I used the command in cmd  as:

```
cmd>HTMLTestRunner.py   pythontc >result.html
```

But i dont want to type manually every time so what can i add in python code ?

Comment: outfile = open("report.html", "w") 
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
               stream= outfile
                     )
    runner.run()

I even used this but it creates empty html file no data inside as we do in htmltestrunner.py pythonname >res.html

Comment: Please, fix indentation